# Emscripten and jquery click callback, issue?

Tags: jquery, callback, click, emscripten

I put here full example, i don't know if is this the right way !?
comple with :

```
emcc jquery001.cpp -o jquery001.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_x_click','_webmain']"
```

it seems that all is well, program work well but ... printf
show always not last printf but prev

initial output :

```
pre-main prep time: 11 ms
jquery001.js:143 
jquery001.js:143  enter webmain
jquery001.js:143  webmain <>
```

exit web main is missig :  printf ( "\n exit webmain");

then a 'click' on a element example  and appears :

```
exit webmain
jquery001.js:143  enter x_click
jquery001.js:143  x_click event <x1>
```

the printf exit web main ... but not          printf ( "\n exit x_click");

what's wrong ?

[ jquery001.html ]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>emcc & jquery</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label id="x1" class="x" >emscripten1</label>
<label id="x2" class="x" >emscripten2</label>
</body>
<script src="jquery001.js"></script>
<script>
Module.ccall('webmain', 'number', ['string'],['']);
</script>
</html>
```

[ jquery001.cpp ]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <string>

extern "C"
{
    int x_click(  char *s ) 
    {
      printf ( "\n enter x_click");
      printf ( "\n x_click event <%s>",s );
      printf ( "\n exit x_click");
      return 0 ;
    }


    int webmain( char *s ) 
    {
        printf ( "\n enter webmain");       
        printf ( "\n webmain <%s>",s);

        int x = EM_ASM_INT({

         $('.x').click(function(e)
         {
             Module.ccall('x_click', 'number', ['string'],[e.target.id]);

         });


          return 0;
        }, NULL);   

        printf ( "\n exit webmain");    

        return 0 ;
    }

}


int main ( void )
{

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emscripten deals with output by buffering the arguments passed to `printf` until it reaches a newline, at which point that string is passed to the `Module.print()` method, which deals with displaying the output. The upshot of this is that if a string is passed to `printf` that doesn't end with a newline, then it won't get printed.

This is similar to how `stdout` is buffered in C, but the differences with Emscripten (at least version 1.36 that I tested with) are that calling `fflush(NULL)` doesn't flush the buffers, and `stderr` is buffered in the same way as `stdout`.

Rectifying your problem is straightforward, you just need to flush the buffers by adding a newline to the end of your final strings, i.e.:

```
printf("\n exit x_click\n");
```

and

```
printf("\n exit webmain\n");
```

Comment: Works perfectly as you indicate to me ( +1 when i reach 15 of reputation ) !